# Cheese diagram in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, sunburst-diagram

How would you implement this with d3.js:

[image]

I started with sunburst diagram, but how to handle pics around circle? How to rotate them? etc. (assume each cheese has its png pic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add images, you can use the [SVG `image` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag). The elements added in this way can be translated and rotated in the usual manner. The code you're going to need is essentially the same as for a pie chart with rotated labels, for which you should be able to find plenty of examples.

Here's a quick and dirty [modified pie chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8194543) that demonstrates the technique.

Comment: Thats cool, and the comparison to rotated labels is uselul. Thanks a lot!